# False sense of security with `snprintf_s`

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, visual-c++-2005

MSVC's "secure" `sprintf` funcions have a template version that 'knows' the size of the target buffer.  However, this code happily paints 567890 over the stack after the end of `bytes`...

```
char bytes[5];
_snprintf_s( bytes, _TRUNCATE, "%s", "1234567890" );
```

Any idea what I do wrong, or is this a known bug?

(I'm working in VS2005 - didn't test in 2008 or 2010)

Comment: Ouch! That's an embarrassing one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It does appear to be [a bug in Visual C++ 2005](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99662/templated-vsnprintf-s-and-snprintf-s-buggy) (I'm having trouble getting to that link; [Google also has it cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Vm5CXvFMgCEJ:https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99662/templated-vsnprintf-s-and-snprintf-s-buggy+_snprintf_s+site:connect.microsoft.com&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)).

I was able to reproduce the problem in Visual C++ 2005.  In Visual C++ 2008 and 2010, the string is correctly truncated (`bytes` contains `1234\0`) and `-1` is returned as expected.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems that the bug report really disappeared from the MS Connect site...

Answer (score 1):

The example is indeed correct. As of version --

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005
Version 8.0.50727.867 (vsvista.050727-8600)
...
Visual C++ 77626-009-0000007-41722
```

-- which includes SP1, the vista hotfix and a few of the library hotfixes --
the above mentioned function

```
template <size_t size>
int _snprintf_s(
   char (&buffer)[size],
   size_t count,
   const char *format [,
      argument] ... 
);
```

*still* is buggy. However, what is really fascinating is that *only* this function of the 4 variant functions

- OK: `int _snprintf_s(char *buffer, size_t sizeOfBuffer, size_t count, :::`
- Buggy: `template <size_t size> int _snprintf_s(char (&buffer)[size], size_t count, :::`
- OK: `int _snwprintf_s` (wide character version)
- OK: `template <size_t size> int _snwprintf_s` (yes, the wide character version is OK)

is buggy, that is if one's using the non-template version it's OK, and if one's using either of the wide character versions it's OK too. Amazing.

Answer (score -6):

Example was wrong.

The code should be:

```
char bytes[5];
_snprintf_s( bytes, 5, _TRUNCATE, "%s", "1234567890" );
```

For the wrong code, it may a bug that the compiler did not give any warning but it would be the weak checking for snprintf.

Comment: -1: The question, which is both old and answered, is talking about the overload of `_snprintf_s` that takes an array of `char` to write to. It doesn't have to take the size because it can get the size from the template parameter. Except that in VC 2005, this was broken.