# strcpy ==> is the visual studio 2008 and 2013 is different for using the code?

Tags: visual-c++

```
class Ikan
{
private:

    char jenis[100];
    int berat;
public:

    void setJenis(char *j)
    {strcpy(jenis, j);}
    char *getJenis()
    {return jenis;}

    void setBerat(int b)
    {berat = b;}
    int getBerat()
    {return berat;}
};
```

========================

> "Error 1   error C4996: '**strcpy**': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details."

Comment: You wrote a code snippet with bad formatting and a diagnostic message you got from your compiler. Do you have any questions?

Comment: Have you used `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`? Have you seen online help for details?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ 'strcpy' gives a Warning (C4996)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012222/c-strcpy-gives-a-warning-c4996)

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the warning with

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

before the first #include. If you use precompiled headers, place the define in the file "StdAfx.h".