# Linked Lists: invalid conversion from char to char* issues

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

There seem to be a few similar questions on here though none of them effectively works (at least using my implementation.) I was hoping I could get some insight on why I'm getting the following error:

> invalid conversion from char to char* [-f permissive]

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include "SLList.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    SLList *newNode;
    char name;
    int id;

    newNode = new SLList;

    for( int a = 0; a < 2; a++ )
    {
       cout << "Type a name: ";
       cin >> name;
       cout << endl << "Type an integer id: ";
       cin >> id;

       newNode->insertFirst(name,id);
    }
    newNode->print();
}
```

And my class is as follows:

```
    SLList::SLList()
{
    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    count = 0;
}

void SLList::print()
{
    cout << "List count: " << count <<endl;
    node *temp;
    temp = first;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        cout <<"Name = " <<temp->name <<endl;
        cout <<"ID = " <<temp->id <<endl;
        cout <<"======================" <<endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
void SLList::insertFirst(char *name, int id)
{
    node *newNode;
    newNode = new node;
    assert (newNode != NULL);
    newNode->name = name;
    newNode->id = id;
    newNode->next = first;
    first = newNode;
    if(last == NULL)
        last = newNode;
    count++;
}
```

When I run the main code using name& under insertFirst(&name,id);

The code runs (not as expected) but it at least compiles though name ends up being the same for each. I am fairly new to pointers but was hoping for a little help.

Thanks.

Comment: `insertFirst`'s first argument is `char*`, you're passing in a `char`. If you call it with `&name` you'll almost certainly end up with undefined behavior at some point, use a `std::string` instead.

Comment: You forgot to make `name` an array.

Comment: user657267, within the class function or in the main function?

Comment: You need define your name in main() as char* name and allocate memory for it for each value you pass to the insert first function. A better way should allocate memory in the insert first function and use strcpy to assign the value.

Comment: Knowing how to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a vital skill, much more valuable than any one bug fix. And not just because it makes our job easier (and therefore more of us will try); it will make the bug much easier for *you* to find.

Comment: @FrankCaligro So you're named `'F'`, and I am `'π'`?? A name held in a single character: `char name;` Really?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is just code to get a better understanding and apply it. I understand what you're saying. In the end does it effect the issue much more (honest question).

Comment: @FrankCaligro Looks like you're just drowning in issues actually. Solve one by one. My point was clearly a semantical, issue  you may start of overthinking you design.

Answer (score 0):

This line:
newNode->name = name;
is the problem.

I'm guessing what you probably want is not actually a single character, but a string for the name.  In that case what you would do is replace that line with:

```
strcpy(newNode.name, name);
```

(don't forget to do #include cstring)

Now, make sure you go look at the strcpy documentation and understand the two arguments that it takes and what it returns.  Make sure that you pass strcpy only null terminated c-strings.

This is okay:

```
char name[6];
strcpy(name, "Grace");  //the compiler makes sure this c string "Grace" has a null terminator
```

This is not okay:

```
char* name1;   //never assigned
char* name2;   //never assigned
strcpy(name1, name2); //strcpy would just copy on into space until it found a null character
```

You may get a warning that strcpy is deprecated, you can see about that warning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012222/c-strcpy-gives-a-warning-c4996/%22here%22). But I am guessing that this is for school, so you can probably safely put off such security issues because a hacker probably doesn't care about your homework assignment. Deprecated just means that a newer version of this function has come out and it is not recommended to use it anymore.

Now, let's talk about the error message you got:
invalid conversion from char to char*

```
newNode->name; //evaluates to a char.
name;          //evaluates to a char pointer.

newNode->name = name    // is a type mismatch because char != char*
```

If instead of copying a whole string, if you really did want just a char, you could do:

```
newNode.name = name
```

or

```
newNode->name = *name
```

the -> is an operator that dereferences the pointer given to it.
You can also dereference a pointer like this: *name.

doing this: newNode->name is the same thing as doing: newNode.*name

Comment: Hey, so did my answer help you?  Are you new to the site? If you try my solution and it works, you should mark it as an answer.