# strcpy compiles on Windows but it doesn't on Linux

Tags: c++, strcpy

I'm learning C++ and trying to write universal code (sorry, I don't know how you call the code that can compiles on Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc.).

I have written the function trimLeft:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const string rows = "rows:";
const string columns = "cols:";
const string data = "data:";

struct dimensions {
    int rows;
    int columns;
};

inline bool exists (const string& name) {
    ifstream f(name.c_str());
    return f.good();
}

string trimLeft(const string& input) {

    if ((input.empty()) || 
        ((input.at(0) != ' ') && (input.at(0) != '\t')))
        return input;
    else {
        char * tab2 = new char[input.length() + 1];
        char *trimmed = new char[input.length() + 1];

        strcpy(tab2, input.c_str());

        bool skip = true;
        int pos = 0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (input.length() + 1); i++) {
            if (skip) {
                if ((tab2[i] == ' ') || (tab2[i] == '\t'))
                    continue;
                else {
                    skip = false;

                    trimmed[pos] = tab2[i];
                    pos++;
                }
            }
            else {
                trimmed[pos] = tab2[i];

                if (tab2[i] == '\0')
                    break;
                else
                    pos++;
            }
        }

        string stringTrimmed(trimmed);

        return stringTrimmed;
    }
}
```

It **compiles** on Windows showing this warning:

> warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe.
>   Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

But in Linux, with the following command:

> g++ FormatMatrix.cpp -o format

I get:

```
error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope
```

Are headers different on each operating system?

**NOTE**:
 And please, stop voting negative: I've got the message.

Comment: `#include <string.h>` . Though it's unclear why you want to use raw `char` arrays to begin with, when you know how to use `std::string`.

Comment: Can you try `#include <cstring>` ?

Comment: Include the [`cstring` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) to make your code portable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik or `#include <cstring>`. ;-)

Comment: Do I have to include <cstring> instead of <string>? Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel _"Do I have to include <cstring> instead of <string>?"_ For sake of portability, yes.

Comment: `<string>`: `std::string` and friends, `<cstring>`: provides C API for string things (`string.h`)

Comment: Why do you use cstrings? You have memory leaks in your code. You allocate memory but you don't free it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Maybe. As I said before: "I'm learning".

Comment: You are doing `new` without `delete`, you definitely have a memory leak.

Comment: Avoid cstrings. Avoid raw pointers. Avoid memory allocation. Use stl containers. You are currently learning bad coding style.

Comment: and `using namespace std` is also a habit you should not acquire. Don't do that.

Comment: @VansFannel _"(sorry, I don't know how you call the code that can compiles on Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc.)"_ It's called _portable code_.

Comment: -4 to ask about something I don’t know (to try lesrn something new). I don’t understand StackOverflow.

Comment: @VansFannel The negative votes are probably from a combination of you trying to learn a bad idea _(resorting to C-style strings when you started with `std::string` -- see also [Trim white space from string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40302))_ and of your code being much longer than necessary to present your problem _(see [mcve])_.

Comment: @VansFannel If you got your question down to just what you need to reproduce the error message on Windows, you'd probably have a duplicate of [C++ 'strcpy' gives a Warning (C4996)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012222/c-strcpy-gives-a-warning-c4996).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible that as an implementation detail for a particular compiler, `<cstring>`, which includes the declaration of `strcpy`, is included (perhaps much further up the inclusion tree) by another header you included.

To ensure that your code is truly portable and standard conforming include the header files for every class and function you call; never take for granted that you get the functionality of another header by including something different.